# Shorter way to query selectors?

Tags: javascript

I have js functions which operate on HTML via CSS selectors, such as:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.purchase-item[data-customer="'+activeCustomer+'"][data-group="'+group+'"]');
```

and variations thereof. These CSS selectors are long and stand out as kind of ugly amidst my otherwise pretty-readable code.

Being new to js, I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is just normal and I'm overthinking it.

Comment: There *may* be a slightly shorter way, but without seeing a [mcve] we can't say. But as it stands I see nothing wrong with it

Comment: You could make it a bit prettier with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: It can't get much shorter if you want to query multiple attributes.

Comment: If you're doing it frequently, you can write a function to construct the selector string, so you don't have to write it out every time.

Comment: `I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is just normal and I'm overthinking it.` Some things, like CSS selectors, can be long. There's no way to simplify a CSS selector like this that returns all the desired elements a nothing more

Comment: Depending on the use case... It's definitely not faster, or less work for the browser, but it gets rid of problems when either `activeCustomer` or `group` contain quotes (or any other invalid characters) and gives some more options with formatting: `[...document.querySelectorAll(".purchase-item")].filter(item => item.dataset.customer === activeCustomer && item.dataset.group === group)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer shorter lines, you could expand it to multiple lines if you're careful about it (and also using [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`.purchase-item` +
                          `[data-customer="${activeCustomer}"]` +
                          `[data-group="${group}"]`
);
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the code a bit more readable (with less context switching between string and code) using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
document.querySelectorAll(`.purchase-item[data-customer="${activeCustomer}"][data-group="${group}"]`);
```

Comment: So glad I asked. Didn't know these existed!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the rows get long like that, I tend to refactor the code into new methods. I also used template literals to make the code a bit more readable.

```
document.querySelectorAll(getCustomerGroups(activeCustomer, group));

function getCustomerGroups(activeCustomer, group) {
  return `.purchase-item[data-customer="${activeCustomer}"][data-group="${group}"]`;
}
```

Comment: Great idea! Thank you.